# reducing woocommerce column spacing

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to narrow the space between columns in woocommerce 2.4.3 on a product page/category page. I want to keep the left product aligned to the left side of the page and the right product aligned to the right in a three column arrangement. I want to reduce the white space between the product. The CSS that I have applied so far is,

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
    float: left;
    margin: 1px 10px 0.1em 1px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

and this does allow me to reduce the spacing, however it does not align the third column to the right of the page. You can [view an image here](http://screencast.com/t/AxbCBcpDWpUO) of the problem. I have also tried this targeting the last item with this, but have not had any luck

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.last, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.last {
    margin-right: 0px !important;
}
```

I would really appreciate it someone had some advise or suggestions to help me out.
Thanks

Comment: The problem here is likely the size of the image, not of the margin.  Your images have to shift to deal with less space in between them.  If you want to still have them span the whole width, you'll have to increase the size of the images proportionately.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Josh, but unfortunately it's not that simple. Woocommerce has coded the size and spacing somewhere that I cannot locate. I have manage to manipulate the spacing with the above code, but not succeed in reducing the spacing between the columns.